# Constructive bubble sort not working as expected

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to create a simple bubble sort in JavaScript and cannot understand why my code is not working, the problem seems to be coming from the second if statement, I do not know the exact problem as the browser I'm testing it in refuses to load the page when using this code.

```
var arr =  [4, 6, 0, 3, -2, 1];
var arr2 = [arr[0]];

arr.forEach(function(elem){
    for(var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
        if(elem < arr2[j]){
            arr2.splice(j, 0, elem);
            break;
        }   

        //if number is largest on last iteration add it to the end of the array
        if(j == arr2.length-1){ 
            console.log(elem);  
            //problem seems to be here 
            arr2[arr2.length] = elem;
        }
    }
});

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: `the browser I'm testing it in refuses to load the page when using this code` What does this mean? What error are you getting? If this is the case, it is unlikely that the error has anything to do with your bubble sort and is likely a syntax error.

Comment: What I mean is that the browser gets stuck on loading the page, so I have to actually close the page for it to stop. It's strange I don't why it's happening.

Comment: … or it could be an infinite loop that blocks the browser.

Comment: I'd examine the logic instead; I think you're blowing up the tab.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I think you're on to something, I'll try adding a `break` in the last if statement

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint and stepping through the script in the browsers debugger. You're looping until you reach `arr2.length` but you're also adding items to `arr2` with your `.splice` call. I bet you're constantly adding items to the array so `j` is never `<arr2.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `elem` to the array with `.splice` if it is lower than `arr[j]` but  you never removing the old instance of `elem`. Conesquently, you're always adding items array and it is always getting larger. You need to take out the old instance of `elem` from the array so the array length remains constant from iteration to iteration.

So, somewhere, you should be passing `1` to the second argument of `splice` to take something out of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice